# SAS search multiple values in a string

Tags: sas

I have two SAS datasets with (assume for simplicity) one char variable in each. The first dataset has a variable with company description (sometimes including city, sometimes not; a messy field) and a second dataset has a variable, where all cities are listed. I need to create variable in a first dataset saying, if any of the cities from 2nd dataset was found or not and the outcome should not contain just 0 or 1 answers, but the city itself.
Is there an easy way to do it without looping INDEXW (or similar) functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's wrong with `indexw`?  Using `proc sql` and `indexw` allows a pretty straightforward solution.

Sample data:

```
data have_messy;
  length messy $100;
  messy = 'this is a city name: brisbane' ; output;
  messy = 'this is a city name: sydney'   ; output;
  messy = 'this is a city name: melbourne'; output;
run;

data have_city;
  length city $20;
  city = 'sydney'  ; output;
  city = 'brisbane'; output;
run;
```

Example query:

```
proc sql noprint;
  create table want as
  select a.*,
         b.city
  from have_messy a
  left join have_city  b on indexw(a.messy, b.city)
  ;
quit;
```

Results:

```
messy                               city 
===============================     =========
this is a city name: sydney         sydney 
this is a city name: brisbane       brisbane 
this is a city name: melbourne
```

Be careful - the above query can return multiple results per row in table a if multiple city names are found.  I suggest you run a follow up step to handle any duplicate rows depending on your requirements.

Comment: Nothing wrong! Just didnt realise I can use that function in join... Learnt a lot today. Thanks!